# elasticsearch custom tokenizer - split token by length

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, tokenize, stringtokenizer, analyzer

I am using elasticsearch version 1.2.1.
I have a use case in which I would like to create a custom tokenizer that will break the tokens by their length up to a certain minimum length. For example, assuming minimum length is 4, the token "abcdefghij" will be split into:
"abcd efgh ij".

I am wondering if I can implement this logic without the need of coding a custom Lucene Tokenizer class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a bit different than the example you've provided, but [NGram Tokenizer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your requirement, if you can't do it using the [pattern tokenizer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html) then you'll need to code up a custom Lucene Tokenizer class yourself. You can create a custom Elasticsearch plugin for it. You can refer to [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-plugins.html#analysis-plugins) for examples about how Elasticsearch plugins are created for custom analyzers.

Comment: I am trying to follow your advise and use pattern tokenizer but I am not sure this functionality can be achieved. I tried is the following pattern: "([.]{0,5})" but it seems to break the token in to characters (probably because of the greedy regex).

Comment: Don't think pattern tokenizer is applicable here based on the docs: "IMPORTANT: The regular expression should match the token separators, not the tokens themselves." But in my case I have no actual seperator.

Comment: I suspected that too. Seems like writing an Elasticsearch plugin with a custom analyzer is the only option left.

Comment: The second link is broken, it just leads to the home page

Answer (score 4):

The Pattern Tokenizer supports a parameter ["group"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html#_configuration_19)

It has a default of "-1", which means to use the pattern for splitting, which is what you saw.

However by defining a group >= 0 in your pattern and setting the group-parameter this can be done! E.g. the following tokenizer will split the input into 4-character tokens:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "(.{4})",
          "group": "1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Analyzing a document via the following:

```
POST my_index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "text": "comma,separated,values"
}
```

Results in the following tokens:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "comm",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "a,se",
      "start_offset": 4,
      "end_offset": 8,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "para",
      "start_offset": 8,
      "end_offset": 12,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "ted,",
      "start_offset": 12,
      "end_offset": 16,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "valu",
      "start_offset": 16,
      "end_offset": 20,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why comma is not part of the tokens? `.` from regex should match comma as well.

Comment: In my test i get the comma included in the tokens, see the updated answer with the results included as well

Comment: Surprisingly if you use link: http://localhost:9200/my_index/_analyze?text=comma,separated,values&analyzer=my_analyzer
Instead of curl command the results are different. Perhaps commas gets weirdly encoded, not sure though. Thanks for the update, that's really a neat way of splitting tokens by length.